# Parsing Twitter Information with jq ("text": null)

Tags: api, twitter, jq

I am trying to do some Twitter-analysis via Twurl and extract some information via jq.

I firstly get some tweets via twurl with the command

```
twurl /1.1/users/search.json?q=judo
```

Then i used the following line to structure the outpot with jq:

```
twurl /1.1/users/search.json?q=judo | jq
```

i get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 173752759,
    "id_str": "173752759",
    "name": "#JudoWorlds ",
    "screen_name": "Judo",
    "location": "Worldwide",
    "description": "The Official Twitter Account of the International Judo Federation ",
    "url": "https:.....",
    "entities": {
      "url": {
        "urls": [
          {
            "url": "https://......",
            "expanded_url": "https://www.ijf.org/news/show/5-must-see-preliminary-round-clashes-2",
            "display_url": "ijf.org/news/show/5-mu…",
            "indices": [
              0,
              23
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "description": {
        "urls": []
      }
    },
    "protected": false,
    "followers_count": 59854,
    "friends_count": 847,
    "listed_count": 529,
    "created_at": "Mon Aug 02 07:55:15 +0000 2010",
    "favourites_count": 7074,
    "utc_offset": null,
    "time_zone": null,
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "verified": true,
    "statuses_count": 16532,
    "lang": null,
    "status": {
      "created_at": "Fri Aug 30 08:27:10 +0000 2019",
      "id": 1167353053282013200,
      "id_str": "1167353053282013184",
      "text": "#JudoWorlds The Alternative Promo \n\n@NeilAdamsJudo https://.....",
      "truncated": false,
      "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
          {
            "text": "JudoWorlds",
            "indices": [
              0,
              11
            ]
          }
        ],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [
          {
            "screen_name": "NeilAdamsJudo",
            "name": "Neil Adams MBE",
            "id": 40488733,
            "id_str": "40488733",
            "indices": [
              36,
              50
            ]
          }
        ],
        "urls": [],
        "media": [
          {
            "id": 1167352899267002400,
            "id_str": "1167352899267002369",
            "indices": [
              51,
              74
            ],
            "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1167352899267002369/pu/img/6yD1r7uaPV7p3y6a.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1167352899267002369/pu/img/6yD1r7uaPV7p3y6a.jpg",
            "url": "https://......",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/0RlLbKLkN8",
            "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/Judo/status/1167353053282013184/video/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
              "thumb": {
                "w": 150,
                "h": 150,
                "resize": "crop"
              },
              "medium": {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 675,
                "resize": "fit"
              },
              "small": {
                "w": 680,
                "h": 383,
                "resize": "fit"
              },
              "large": {
                "w": 1280,
                "h": 720,
                "resize": "fit"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "extended_entities": {
        "media": [
          {
            "id": 1167352899267002400,
            "id_str": "1167352899267002369",
            "indices": [
              51,
              74
            ],
            "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1167352899267002369/pu/img/6yD1r7uaPV7p3y6a.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1167352899267002369/pu/img/6yD1r7uaPV7p3y6a.jpg",
            "url": "https://.....",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/0RlLbKLkN8",
            "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/Judo/status/1167353053282013184/video/1",
            "type": "video",
            "sizes": {
              "thumb": {
                "w": 150,
                "h": 150,
                "resize": "crop"
              },
              "medium": {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 675,
                "resize": "fit"
              },
              "small": {
                "w": 680,
                "h": 383,
                "resize": "fit"
              },
              "large": {
                "w": 1280,
                "h": 720,
                "resize": "fit"
              }
            },
            "video_info": {
              "aspect_ratio": [
                16,
                9
              ],
              "duration_millis": 48800,
              "variants": [
                {
                  "bitrate": 256000,
                  "content_type": "video/mp4",
                  "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1167352899267002369/pu/vid/480x270/v4nkTg6qs9rpLq8M.mp4?tag=10"
                },
                {
                  "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
                  "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1167352899267002369/pu/pl/SQN57QxQFYcKWV7l.m3u8?tag=10"
                },
                {
                  "bitrate": 2176000,
                  "content_type": "video/mp4",
                  "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1167352899267002369/pu/vid/1280x720/8cyNocB_8CRjwVCI.mp4?tag=10"
                },
                {
                  "bitrate": 832000,
                  "content_type": "video/mp4",
                  "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1167352899267002369/pu/vid/640x360/uy2U7D_AEmbLdqEK.mp4?tag=10"
                }
              ]
            },
            "additional_media_info": {
              "monetizable": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
      "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
      "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
      "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
      "geo": null,
      "coordinates": null,
      "place": null,
      "contributors": null,
      "is_quote_status": false,
      "retweet_count": 4,
      "favorite_count": 17,
      "favorited": false,
      "retweeted": false,
      "possibly_sensitive": false,
      "lang": "en"
    },
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "is_translator": false,
    "is_translation_enabled": false,
    "profile_background_color": "0099CC",
    "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1057928008797970433/O3l2sKj0_normal.jpg",
    "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1057928008797970433/O3l2sKj0_normal.jpg",
    "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/173752759/1565853008",
    "profile_link_color": "0C3C42",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "8F320A",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "F2CF41",
    "profile_text_color": "000000",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "has_extended_profile": false,
    "default_profile": false,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "following": false,
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "notifications": false,
    "translator_type": "none"
  },
```

Because i am only interested in certain informations i tried to get the name and the text of the tweet with the following command:

```
twurl /1.1/users/search.json?q=judo | jq ".[] | { name: .name, text: .text }"
```

and i get this:

```
{
  "name": "#JudoWorlds ",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "#WeAreGBJudo",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "CBJ",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Santos Futebol Clube",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Marius Vizer",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "FF Judo",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Santos FC     ",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "USA Judo",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "全日本柔道連盟 -ゴジラジャパン-",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Vila Belmiro",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Deutscher Judo-Bund",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Bruno Secco",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Bobby Judo",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "African Judo Union",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "JudoInside.com",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "For competitive judo",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Judo Canada",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Neil Adams MBE",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Sophie Cox",
  "text": null
}
{
  "name": "Galatasaray Judo",
  "text": null
}
```

Why is this and how can i fix it?

I tried other commands like :

```
twurl /1.1/search/tweets.json?q=afd | jq ".[] | { name: .name, text: .text }"
```

but got the error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "name"
```

Comment: Please explain what problem you're seeing. The jq output is coherent with the filter you applied (meaning there isn't any `text` field in the input JSON).

Comment: there is a `text` in `status`, maybe you should try `.[]|{name,text:status.text}`?

Comment: Raphael - Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  What output are you expecting?  The input has two "text" keys at different depths.  Please also try to ensure the input is valid JSON, and preferably not much more than is needed to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need nested 'text' value from 'status' field you should use:

```
.[] | { name: .name, text: .status.text }
```

Or shorter version:

```
.[] | { name, text: .status.text }
```